# selecting any particular style attribute of any element

Tags: jquery

I have a div having different inline style attributes. Out of them I want to access the value of just "background-color" attribute using jquery. Please help somebody :(

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

This is how:

```
var attribute = $('#myelement').css('background-color');
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the value

```
$("#yourDivId").css("background-color");
```

To Set the value

```
$("#yourDivId").css("background-color","yourNewColorValue");
```

Using class selector

Getter

```
$(".classOfYourDiv").css("background-color");
```

Setter

```
$(".classOfYourDiv").css("background-color","YourNewColorValue");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery("#elementID").css("background-color");
```